# iOS: How to display special characters in Swift [NSString]

Tags: ios, xcode, node.js, swift, socket.io

I am sending data via **socket.io** my app, which I want to embed the text of a parameter in a `UILabel`

**Javascript server**

```
socket.emit("app",{ac:"organización"})
```

**iOS App**

```
var ac = self.jsonOFsocket["ac"] as String
//ac === "organización"
self.label.text = ac
//self.label.text === "organizaci\U00f3n"
```

1. The socket.io the app sends unencrypted characters.
2. The app successfully receives all characters
3. The app shows different symbols

**I try to do this:**

```
func utf(txt:String) -> NSString {
   var newTxt = NSString(format:txt, NSUTF8StringEncoding)
   newTxt.precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping
   return newTxt
}

var ac = self.jsonOFsocket["ac"] as String
//ac === "organización"
self.label.text = uft(ac)
//self.label.text === "organizaciââ¥n"
```

**This is important:**

```
organizaciââ¥n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Objective-C way:

```
NSData *data = [MyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *stringWithSpecialCharacters = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
```

You'll have to store the proper string format on your server too and make sure it returns the right string via curl.

Comment: **Thanks**, it has served me well !!
 `var ns = NSString(string: "poblaci\\U00f3n")

var data:NSData = ns.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
var sc = NSString(data:data,encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding)`