# Allowing special characters in URLRequest httpBody

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

here is what I am doing to post request to server.

```
    let urlStr = "someurl"
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlStr)!)
    request.addValue(accessToken!, forHTTPHeaderField: "accessToken")


    let postString = self.makeRequestString(dict: paramDict)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
    let session = URLSession.shared

    request.timeoutInterval = 60

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in 

       }
```

here is method description of  makeRequestString

```
func makeRequestString(dict:Dictionary<String,AnyObject>) -> String {
    let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: .prettyPrinted)
    let str = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
    return "key=" + str!
}
```

The issue I am facing is if my dictionary parameters has some special characters in it like **!@#$%^&*(*)** then server is not accepting the request and giving some undesired result.

Any suggestions or pointers in correcting code where I am missing anything.

**EDIT:**

For now I get desired response from the server if I change the following line of code in my method **makeRequestString**

```
    let str = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)?.replacingOccurrences(of: "&", with: "%26")
```

Comment: Maybe try to escape those characters

Comment: first remove special characters in your string than make to your  paramDict and sent to server

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/29502001/5177699

Answer (score 0):

Try with this encoding:

```
request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
```